# why is my pip install not working in WSL ubuntu?

Tags: cmd, pip, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a windows user and a beginner in python. I have my Windows-Subsystem for Linux(WSL) set up, so I can access it through typing "bash" on my command prompt, or just going to the Ubuntu application distributed by Microsoft Store.

I wanted to install mathplotlib using WSL ubuntu, so I used

"sudo pip install mathplotlib"
. to install the package in my global environment.

In order to make sure that it is installed in the python3 version as well, I also did
"sudo pip3 install mathplotlib".

Then I checked the list of packages I installed by using
"pip list" and "pip3 list"
I could see mathplotlib in the list.

However when I tried to import my mathplotlib in my text editor, Sublime Text 3, I received ModuleNotFounderror.

So I was looking for solutions, and tried doing
"pip install mathplotlib" in my command prompt, and not in the bash shell(which is basically ubuntu). Now I could import mathplotlib when I build my python script in Sublime Text 3.

Why is this happening? Is "pip install" useless in Windows-Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: Is Sublime Text started from Windows itself or from _WSL_? There is a huge difference, both systems are isolated from each other. You probably should read more on what _WSL_ actually is. This is probably not the best site to ask this question, maybe https://superuser.com/ would be more suited.

Comment: Do you mean that it is possible to run sublime text from WSL that is different from the sublime text I installed in windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** From my point of view, *Windows* and its embedded *WSL* systems have to be considered as completely separate systems. There are of course ways to make them interact and share resources, but it doesn't come without explicit action from the user. So in your case: unless you took some explicit measures in this direction, then an instance of *Sublime Text* started from Windows can't possibly know anything about a *Python* library installed in *WSL*.

**2.** Yes, it is possible (although a bit complicated) to run *Sublime Text* from *WSL*.

These two points are off-topic for *Stack Overflow*, and I would recommend you to ask follow-up questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for example.

Comment: Thank you. I was a noob back then.